# Amazon EC2 Windows 2008 FTP Issues - Cannot get directory listing

Tags: iis-7, ftp, amazon-ec2, filezilla

Does anyone have a foolproof way to FTP to Windows 2008 EC2 Instances?  I had mine working perfectly after following a lot of online guides from other users.  Then it started deteriorating, intermittently giving a "Failed to get directory listing error".   Login was still all fine.  Now the error is permanent and I cannot update my web site.

Amazon, of course, won't respond to any emails unless I have a support package, yet they have no documentation on setting up FTP to their servers.

I was using old IIS6 based FTP - when I was able to connect and when it stopped working I tried the new FTP 7 as detailed here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/263/installing-and-configuring-ftp-on-iis-7/

Now I cannot connect at all to the server, let alone getting a directory listing.

Please someone come to my rescue!

My default security group has ports 20 & 21 forwarding for my IP address.  As per the article above I have ports 4900-4910 open to 0.0.0.0/0

My client is FileZilla using FTPS (was just FTP with IIS6 FTP server), Connecting with Passive falling back to Active.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well and its not the easiest thing to find a fix. The following link finally worked for me. Mainly the following.

1. In IIS, highlight the top-level server (not the FTP site). Click FTP Firewall Support. Under Data Channel Port Range, set a small range, e.g. 41000-41099. Under External IP Address to your Elastic IP Address.
2. Open the Windows firewall for the ftpsvc. DISable the StatefulFtp global setting:

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=FTP_Service action=allow service=ftpsvc protocol=TCP dir=in
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable

3. From an administrative command prompt, restart the Microsoft FTP Service to make sure all the changes take effect:

net stop ftpsvc
net start ftpsvc

4. Open the corresponding 100 ports, e.g. 21 and 41000-41099, in your EC2 Security Group.